# How to use tryCatch with withTimeout to timeout Rcpp function without stopping execution of script

Tags: r, try-catch, rcpp

I want to place a time limit on a function that I'm calling, so that if it times out then it just moves onto the next part of the script (which I am running by `source("...")`). The function is written using Rcpp and has `checkUserInterrupt();` included frequently throughout. I have been using `withTimeout` in the `R.utils` package with the option `onTimeout = silent`, but timing out is still pausing execution of the script.

I then ran this within `tryCatch` to return `NULL` in the case of any errors, but it is still stopping my script. I have included a short function that replicates this issue.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace Rcpp;

void sleep_fn(int n) // sleeps for n seconds
{
  std::chrono::seconds dura( n );
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int sleep_for(int n) // sleeps for n seconds and then returns n
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    checkUserInterrupt();
    sleep_fn(1);
  }
  return(n);
}
```

Now, for comparison, let's run this as well as the R command `Sys.sleep()`. See that this is working as it's supposed to, but for `sleep_for` it's still throwing an exception which stops my script.

```
> tryCatch(withTimeout(Sys.sleep(10), timeout = 5), error = function(ex) return(NULL))
NULL

> tryCatch(withTimeout(sleep_for(10), timeout = 5), error = function(ex) return(NULL))
Error in .Call(<pointer: 0x108cc17b0>, n) : reached elapsed time limit

> tryCatch(withTimeout(sleep_for(10), timeout = 5, onTimeout = "silent"), error = function(ex) return(NULL))
Error in .Call(<pointer: 0x108cc17b0>, n) : reached elapsed time limit
```

Why isn't `tryCatch` doing what I think it should? And is there anything I can do in order to get it to work?

(I'm using R version 4.0.3, Rcpp version 1.0.6, R.utils version 2.10.1)
Edit: and am on MacOS 11.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Try this template and see if it works. I have used it and it exists silently.

```
# Timeout is in seconds
# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.7.0/topics/withTimeout
tryCatch(
  {
    withTimeout(some_function(), timeout = 60)                    
  }
  ,TimeoutException = function(ex) {
    print("Timeout of 60 seconds reached. Function will not be completely run.")
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- I'm afraid it's still giving the same problem with the example I included in the question:

`Error in .Call(<pointer: 0x108cc17b0>, n) : reached elapsed time limit `

Comment: I'm not having any trouble with `tryCatch` when the function inside `withTimeout` _isn't_ using Rcpp. Only when the function uses Rcpp and therefore is stopped using `checkUserInterrupt`.